# How do I create a new community on Stack Exchange?

Tags: stack-exchange

I want to create a community on a Stack Exchange website for welcoming discussions about Tamil language literature. How can I do that?

Being a registered user of Stack Exchange, is there any special privilege required to create a community? Or, are any administrative people there who only can create a new community on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Looks interesting, I was searching for this question for the same reason - to create a tamil community!

Comment: @GiridharanVenkatapathy ...I'm perhaps "following in your footsteps" (or at least thinking about it), and would appreciate hearing from you about your experience... Did you venture out and try? If not, why not, please?! Importantly, I KNOW I CANNOT meet the requirements of "private beta" myself without some form of spamming folks, as maybe I might be doing now! ... Thanks much for any reply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

This is the place for new proposals:

> Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, where users come together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed, discussed, and the best go on to beta. See the [faq](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

There are no proposals yet for anything Tamil-related, and it does not look there is any [SE site](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) either.

Comment: Related [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/133145)